# Which listener should I use for the letters in a wordsearch android application?

Tags: android, wordsearch

```
....
case 5:
    sizeperbutton = sizeOfLayout/5;
    for( i = 0; i<25; i++) {
       buttons[i] = new Button(this)
       ll.addView(buttons[i]);
       ViewGroup.LayoutParams mParams = buttons[i].getLayoutParams();
       mParams.height = sizeperbutton;
       mParams.width = sizeperbutton;
       int j = (int)(Math.random()*26);
       buttons[i].setText(letterEN[j]);
       buttons[i].setTag(i);
       buttons[i].setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

           @Override
           public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
               Object tag = view.getTag();
               if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                 /* Set the background drawable only for the button  I've clicked, and get its text and append it to a textView*/
               }
               if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                 /* Set the background drawable all the buttons I dragged through my finger and append their letters to the same textView*/
               }
               if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                 /*Release touching, check if the text which is stacked to the textView is contained by a list.*/
               }
               return false;
           }
       });
  }
```

It creates an area with 5 buttons horizontally and vertically in my gameactivity. 
All of them get a random letter and get the touch listener which is I think not adequate for clicking more objects simultaneously, it only works for just one button. I'd appreciate any sources or codes. I'd taken a long-long research but finally I had to ask for information. Here is what I want to attain: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NRIvZioTdMc.

Comment: If you copy-and-paste your code into your question and describe what you want to attain rather than linking to a Youtube tutorial, you'll have a better chance at getting an answer on here.

Comment: Ok I will vow it in the future, it was my first time here at stackoverflow, but I think it is somewhat comprehensible. Leastwise I hope :D.

Comment: Better now. And what about summarizing the content of the Youtube video? Welcome to Stackoverflow :D